# Trying to improve execution time of Julia code

Tags: octave, julia, grammar

I need to write a code to generate a string using a grammar with just one rule. For example, if the rule is "G -> [G+G]", and we apply the rule to "G", the result is the string "[G+G]"; if we apply it to the previous result, we obtain "[[G+G]+[G+G]]" and so on. In other words, it's about rewritting the axiom (left side of the rule) a given number of times,
following the rule.

I've been given a piece of code written in Octave that implements this operation (I won't include the code because it's a bit long, but I will if it's necessary for understanding or answering the question). What I need to do is to write an equivalent function in Julia; so I wrote this

```
    function generate_developedstring(axiom::ASCIIString, genome::ASCIIString, iterations::Int8)
        tic()
        developedstring = axiom
        for i=1:iterations
            developedstring = replace(developedstring, axiom, genome)
        end
        toc()
        return developedstring
    end
```

In the example I wrote earlier, axiom would be "G" and genome "[G+G]".

According to the benchmark times published is julialang.org, Julia should be way faster than Octave, but in this case, Octave is twice as fast as Julia
(I used the same axiom, genome and iterations for both codes and I measured times with tic toc functions).

Is there any way to make the Julia code faster?

Edit: First of all, thank you all so much for your comments. I will show you the Octave code I've been given (I didn't write it):

```
function axiom = ls(genome)
  tic
  ProductionSystem = ['[=>[ ]=>] +=>+ -=>- G=>',genome];
  rule = extract(ProductionSystem);

  n_Rules = length(rule);

  % starting string
  axiom = 'G';

  % iterations (choose only from 1 to 7, >= 8 critical,
  % depends on the string and on the computer !!
  n_Repeats = 3;

%CALCULATE THE STRING
%=================================

for i = 1:n_Repeats
    % a single letter (axiom)
    axiomINcells = cellstr(axiom);
    for j = 1:n_Rules
        % find all occurrences of that axiom
        hit = strfind(axiom, rule(j).pre);
        if (length(hit) >= 1)
            for k = hit
                % perform the rule
                % (replace 'pre' by 'post')
                axiomINcells{k} = rule(j).pos;
            end
        end
    end
    axiom = [];
    for j = 1:length(axiomINcells)
        % put all strings together
        axiom = [axiom, axiomINcells{j}];
    end
end
toc

function rule = extract(ProductionSystem)
% rules are separated by space character, and pre and post sides are
% separtated by '->'
% e.g. F->FF G->F[+G][-G]F[+G][-G]FG

i=0;
while (~isempty(ProductionSystem))
    i=i+1;
    [rule1,ProductionSystem] = strtok(ProductionSystem,' ');
    [rule(i).pre,post] = strtok(rule1,'=>');
    rule(i).pos = post(3:end);
    if (~isempty(ProductionSystem)) ProductionSystem=ProductionSystem(2:end);   % delete separator
    end
end
```

About the Julia version I'm using, it's 0.4.7. You also asked me how fast I need it to run; I just need to write a code as fast as posible, and the fact that Octave was faster made me think that I was doing something wrong.
Thank you again.

Comment: I've done some more testing increasing the number of iterations; finally Julia is way faster than Octave. Whatever the case, mi program will usually have a low number of iterations, so the question is still the same.

Comment: A few suggestions first: use `@time` macro instead of `tic`/`toc`/ inside function, and benchmark twice, to exclude compilation time. You might get more useful help for this kind of performance question if you post a minimal, runnable example on the discussion forum at https://discourse.julialang.org

Comment: Is the Octave code all one vectorized call? If it is, then you're not comparing Octave itself. Rather, you'd be comparing Julia to that well-optimized function which is likely implemented in C. You shouldn't expect Julia to do better than C, though it should usually be close.

Comment: I spent some time on this and the Julia version seems pretty fast – the iterated string version is about as fast as recursively printing a single string directly, and also about the same pre-allocating the right amount of space up front. Can you post the Octave code so we can see what it's doing?

Comment: are you using Julia v0.4 or earlier? `ASCIIString` is deprecated in the current release (v0.5). also, is there a compelling reason to use an 8-bit integer as your iteration count? I tried `generate_developedstring("a", "aa", Int8(10))` and the function consistently takes less than a millisecond to execute on my Mac laptop. how fast do you need it to run?

Comment: assuming your `replace` function is making a new copy each time, this can be replaced with a *mutating* version of the function, (named `replace!`) that mutates an existing object instead, avoiding memory allocations. For that to work, `developedstring` could have some padding, to ensure it doesn't have to change size at each iteration.

Comment: `replace!` does not exist? Since `String`s are immutable.

Comment: I get 780ns on Julia 0.5 and 580ns on Julia 0.6 for 2 iterations. So it's a bit faster in recent Julia versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you specify the `genome` as a rule instead of a pattern? I mean, for example `genome = ax -> "[$ax,$ax]"`.

Compare these two implementations, the first of which is the same as yours:

```
function genstring(axiom::String, genome::String, iter::Int)
    str = axiom
    for i in 1:iter
        str = replace(str, axiom, genome)
    end
    return str
end
```

And then with an anonymous function:

```
genome = ax -> "[$ax,$ax]"

function genstring_(axiom::String, genome, n::Int)
    if n < 1
        return axiom
    end
    return genstring_(genome(axiom), genome, n-1)
end
```

On version 0.5, with `BenchmarkTools`:

```
julia> @benchmark genstring("G", "[G,G]", 2)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  752.00 bytes
  allocs estimate:  15
  --------------
  minimum time:     745.950 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      801.067 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        1.006 μs (14.30% GC)
  maximum time:     50.271 μs (96.63% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     119
  time tolerance:   5.00%
  memory tolerance: 1.00%

julia> @benchmark genstring_("G", genome, 2)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  352.00 bytes
  allocs estimate:  9
  --------------
  minimum time:     397.562 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      414.149 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        496.511 ns (13.06% GC)
  maximum time:     24.410 μs (97.18% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     201
  time tolerance:   5.00%
  memory tolerance: 1.00%
```

It scales better:

```
julia> @benchmark genstring("G", "[G,G]", 10)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  18.00 kb
  allocs estimate:  71
  --------------
  minimum time:     93.569 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      95.959 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        103.429 μs (3.05% GC)
  maximum time:     4.216 ms (97.14% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     1
  time tolerance:   5.00%
  memory tolerance: 1.00%

julia> @benchmark genstring_("G", genome, 10)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  14.13 kb
  allocs estimate:  49
  --------------
  minimum time:     3.072 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      3.597 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        5.703 μs (29.78% GC)
  maximum time:     441.515 μs (98.24% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     8
  time tolerance:   5.00%
  memory tolerance: 1.00%
```

As far as I know, string interpolation isn't superfast, so there could further optimizations.

Comment: is it true that anonymous functions suffer almost no performance hit in Julia v0.6? If so, then your second solution will be even faster on the development copy of Julia.

Comment: That performance improvement happened already in v0.5. There will be a new implementation of strings, though. Not sure what performance implications that has.

Comment: Thank you so much, the program is so much faster with an anonymous function.